# Delete Query using Inner joins on more than two tables

Tags: sql, db2

I want to delete records from a table using inner joins on more than two tables. Say if I have tables A,B,C,D with A's pk shared in all other mentioned tables. Then how to write a delete query to delete records from table D using inner joins on table B and A since the conditions are fetched from these two tables. I need this query from DB2 perspective. I am not using IN clause or EXISTS because of their limitations.

Comment: delete from table A inner join table B inner join table C on A.pk=B.pk and B.pk=c.pk and some conditions of B.This may work on mysql but I want it for DB2.

Answer (score 14):

From your description, I take the schema as:

> A(pk_A, col1, col2, ...)
>
> B(pk_B, fk_A, col1, col2, ..., foreign key fk_A references A(pk_A))
>
> C(pk_c, fk_A, col1, col2, ..., foreign key fk_A references A(pk_A))
>
> D(pk_d, fk_A, col1, col2, ..., foreign key fk_A references A(pk_A))

As you say DB2 will allow only 1000 rows to be deleted if IN clause is used. I don't know about DB2, but Oracle allows only 1000 manual values inside the IN clause. There is not such limit on subquery results in Oracle at least. EXISTS should not be a problem as any database, including Oracle and DB2 checks only for existence of rows, be it one or a million.

There are three scenarios on deleting data from table D:

1. You want to delete data from table D in which fk_A (naturally) refers to a record in table A using column A.pk_A:

   ```
   DELETE FROM d
   WHERE EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
            FROM a
           WHERE a.pk_A = d.fk_A
   );
   ```
2. You want to delete data from table D in which fk_A refers to a record in table A, and that record in table A is also referred to by column B.fk_A. We do not want to delete the data from D that is in A but not in B. We can write:

   ```
   DELETE FROM d
   WHERE EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
            FROM a
      INNER JOIN b ON a.pk_A = b.fk_A
           WHERE a.pk_A = d.fk_A
   );
   ```
3. The third scenario is when we have to delete data in table D that refers to a record in table A, and that record in A is also referred by columns B.fk_A and table C.fk_A. We want to delete ***only*** that data from table D which is common in all the four tables - A, B, C and D. We can write:

   ```
   DELETE FROM d
   WHERE EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
            FROM a
      INNER JOIN b ON a.pk_A = b.fk_A
      INNER JOIN c ON a.pk_A = c.fk_A
           WHERE a.pk_A = d.fk_A
   );
   ```

Depending upon your requirement you can incorporate one of these queries.

Note that "=" operator would return an error if the subquery retrieves more than one line. Also, I don't know if DB2 supports ANY or ALL keywords, hence I used a simple but powerful EXISTS keyword which performs faster than IN, ANY and ALL.

Also, you can observe here that the subqueries inside the EXISTS clause use "SELECT 1", not "SELECT a.pk" or some other column. This is because EXISTS, in any database, looks for only existence of rows, not for any particular values inside the columns.

Comment: Hi Yogesh R. Thanks for your solution.got some clarity on this. But after trying this way all entries from my table got deleted. After investigating in the conditions i found that EXISTS clause is causing some problem for my query. Still many thanks for your help.

Comment: Just put a "SELECT * FROM d" instead of "DELETE FROM d" in above queries to see exactly what rows will be deleted. If you are sure that these are the rows to delete, go on with the deletion. Try doing this with all the three scenarios. Do not forget to issue a ROLLBACK if you want to undo the changes. Best luck!

Comment: Also, for the first scenario, all the rows from D will be deleted if column D.fk_A contains a value for every row. Try the other scenarios. If it fails then issue a ROLLBACK.

Answer (score 1):

Based on ['Using SQL to delete rows from a table using INNER JOIN to another table'](http://www.databasically.com/2011/08/31/using-sql-to-delete-rows-from-a-table-using-inner-join)

> The key is that you specify the name of the table to be deleted from
>   as the SELECT. So, the JOIN and WHERE do the selection and limiting,
>   while the DELETE does the deleting. You're not limited to just one
>   table, though. If you have a many-to-many relationship (for instance,
>   Magazines and Subscribers, joined by a Subscription) and you're
>   removing a Subscriber, you need to remove any potential records from
>   the join model as well.

```
DELETE subscribers
     FROM subscribers INNER JOIN subscriptions 
       ON subscribers.id = subscriptions.subscriber_id
     INNER JOIN magazines 
       ON subscriptions.magazine_id = magazines.id
     WHERE subscribers.name='Wes';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from D 
where fk  = (select d.fk from D d,A a,B b where a.pk = b.fk and b.fk = d.fk )
```

this should work

Comment: I want to delete from a single table ie D and from your above comment i doubt if delete from multiple tables in a single query you shown is not possible.

Comment: How many tables do you want the data to be deleted from? Can you please clarify your schema? You mention A's PK is shared in all the other mentioned tables. What exactly is the relationship there? Is it PK-FK type? Also, what is the relationship of table D with B and C? And why not to use IN or EXISTS while "=" returns an error if the subquery retrieves more than one row?
Until you clarify all these points, yours remains an unclear question.

Comment: i want entries to b deleted from only one table D where D' fk is A's pk. this pk is shared in tables B C and D as fk. in DB2 if i use IN clause then limited number of entries get deleted ie 1000. more entries may cause problem. EXISTS also cause more data entries to b deleted from table.

Comment: Wait, I will answer in a while.