# DB2 Delete with Inner Joins

Tags: sql, db2, sql-delete

Trying to delete from a table where there are matching records in other tables.

I've tried different variations of this, but this one returns:

> SQL Error [42601]: [SQL0199] Keyword INNER not expected. Valid tokens: USE SKIP WAIT WITH FETCH LIMIT ORDER WHERE OFFSET.

It's basically a cross library / cross database, but can't get DB2 to play along.  The Select works just fine, if I replace the delete with SELECT *

```
 DELETE a
  FROM INHOUSE.ANDREWCAT a
   INNER JOIN ERPLIB.SRBPRG b ON
   a.PSPRDC  = b.PGPRDC
   INNER JOIN ERPLIB.SRBRSD  c 
   ON 
    b.PGIRGP = c.RDSRTY 
   AND c.RDTOFI = a.EPNUM AND c.RDSRTY = c.RDWHAT 
   AND a.EPNUM = 'REM104'
```

Comment: I'm no DB2 expert, but I did find this, which offers a potential solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523373/delete-query-using-inner-joins-on-more-than-two-tables

Comment: Another idea might be to solve this at the schema level. You can use cascading deletes so that a delete on one table causes deletes on tables with foreign key links. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10/14.10?topic=format-using-delete-cascade-option I have worked with this sort of thing in a Postgres database before, and it can have some downsides as well. Typically, writes (deletes) can only happen on a single master DB. The deletes will cause locks on the tables where deletes happen. You get enough of these deletes happening at once and you can lock up your DB accidentally.

Comment: You have `DELETE a FROM...`. This should not work. Do you just have it as a left-over after you tried `SELECT`?

Comment: @PM77-1  DELETE a should work as it is an alias.  I also tried DELETE FROM INHOUSE.ANDREWCAT  INNER JOIN... then it doesn't like the keyword INNER.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000939.html  as you can see it's always `DELETE FROM`.

Comment: Why join? `delete from table where exists...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB2 does not support the syntax you ware using.

Instead:

```
DELETE INHOUSE.ANDREWCAT a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM ERPLIB.SRBPRG b JOIN
                   ERPLIB.SRBRSD  c 
                   ON b.PGIRGP = c.RDSRTY
              WHERE a.PSPRDC  = b.PGPRDC AND
                    c.RDTOFI = a.EPNUM AND
                    c.RDSRTY = c.RDWHAT AND
                    a.EPNUM = 'REM104'
             );
```